# Flutter - Color of Overlapped Lines in Canvas

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

When I draw lines on a CustomPainter's canvas using code like this:

```
var paint = Paint()
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
  ..strokeWidth = 4.0
  ..color = Colors.grey;

canvas.drawLine(fromOffsetA, toOffsetB, paint);
canvas.drawLine(fromOffsetC, toOffsetD, paint);
```

If the two lines partly overlap over one another, then the section of the lines that overlap show the line color as being darker than in the sections of the line that do not overlap.

I am guessing that this is by design so, my question is, how do I draw lines that overlap one another and at the same time prevent the lines' color from darkening in the overlapped sections?

I am thinking I need to set the paint's Blendmode to a specific value or something along those lines?

Comment: your color is not fully opaque, that's why

Comment: Ah, yes @pskink... you are absolutely right. In the actual code, the line color's opacity was set to 0.15. Feel free to answer the post as in the comment and I'll accept it as solved.